# how to get filename given FileData object in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a FileData object file, where when I `print(file)` I will get:

`<FileData ID_0a0eebac2.dcm (ID_0a0eebac2.dcm)>`

I am hoping to extract the name of the file, "ID_0a0eebac2.dcm", from this object. How can I do this?

Comment: From the docs, `file.get_name()` https://digidotcom.github.io/python-devicecloud/latest/filedata.html

Answer (score 0):

This way you can do it

In python the name is an attribute of IOWrapper : 'https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html'

```py
file = open('ID_0a0eebac2.dcm')
#to get the name of the file you can do this
file_name = file.name # the name of the file is saved as an attribute of the object
```

If you want to make a function

```py
def get_file_name(file):
    return file.name
```

I hope you got your answer

Comment: when I try to do print (file.name) I get `'FileData' object has no attribute 'name'`